# React-Router 5 and Express - Catch-All Route Fallback

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, routes, react-router

I'm working on a MERN stack-based project with Redux, react-router, and Webpack 4 and for the life of me I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. My development build works fine, but when I run my production build, my catch-all fallback route does not work. The index.html file only works because I'm using `express.static`, when I remove that it doesn't work at all. The react router works fine when I navigate to localhost:3000 but if I try to manually navigate to localhost:3000/about there is an Internal Server Error. So I'm assuming the `app.get` request is just not working at all for some reason. Here is my server code:

```
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';

import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import cors from 'cors';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const PORT = process.env.PORT;
const MONGODB_URI = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
const history = require('connect-history-api-fallback');

const app = express();

app.use(cors())

//DB setup
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URI);
var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
    console.log('We have been connected!');
});


if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") {
    app.use(history());
    const webpack = require('webpack');
    const webpackDevMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware');
    //require webpack config
    const config = require('../../webpack.dev.config.js');
    //create compiler
    const compiler = webpack(config);
    //use webpack-dev-middleware to serve the bundles
    app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
        publicPath: config.output.publicPath
    }));
    //enable HMR
    app.use(require('webpack-hot-middleware')(compiler));
} else {
    app.use(express.static("dist"));

    app.get("*", (req, res) => {
      res.sendFile(path.join("./dist", "index.html"));
    });
}



//Listen
app.listen(PORT, function() {
    console.log('Server is listening...');
});
```

I would appreciate any help in figuring this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the error you're receiving is this: **TypeError: path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile**

To fix this, you should use `path.resolve` instead of `path.join` and adjust the path accordingly:

```js
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve("./dist", "index.html"));
});
```

Comment: The only error I'm getting is an Internal Server Error 500. I was originally using path.resolve but the issue was the same.

Comment: Do you have any additional information about what that 500 error is? Unfortunately, I wouldn't know how else to help since a 500 error could be any number of things. I only assumed the above error because I copied your code into a sample project and that's what I got.

Comment: Ooh actually, your answer works for me! While fiddling around with it I made a typo that was breaking it, it was an issue with the path. Thanks so much, I really appreciate the help!